# Paginate result set from $wpdb->get_results()

Tags: comments, pagination

Is there an easy way to paginate the result set coming from $wpdb->get_results()?

I want to get a paginated list of a user's comments on the author_archive page - some of the users of the community have > 500 comments, so pagination is important.

Is there an in-built way of doing this with WordPress, or do I need to build it myself?

[Updated to add code]

```
<!-- Show comments -->
<?php 
$querystr = "
    SELECT comment_ID, comment_post_ID, post_title, LEFT(comment_content,100) as comment_content, comment_date_gmt
    FROM $wpdb->comments, $wpdb->posts
    WHERE user_id = $thisauthor->ID
    AND comment_post_id = ID
    AND comment_approved = 1
    ORDER BY comment_ID DESC
    LIMIT 100
 ";


$comments_array = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

if ($comments_array): ?>
    <div id="author-comments-list">
        <h2>Recent Comments </h2>
        <ul>
            <? 
                $odd_even = "odd";
                foreach ($comments_array as $comment):
                    echo "<li class='$odd_even'><a href='". get_bloginfo('url') ."/?p=".$comment->comment_post_ID."/#comment-". $comment->comment_ID ."'>". $comment->post_title ."</a> : ".mysql2date('l jS F, Y, g:ia',$comment->comment_date_gmt);
                    echo "<div class='author-comments-content'>".$comment->comment_content."</li>";
                    $odd_even = ($odd_even == "odd" ? "even" : "odd");
               endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div> 
<? endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the function [paginate_links()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) for any pagination.

For your specific case:

```
$total = $wpdb->get_var("
    SELECT COUNT(comment_ID)
    FROM $wpdb->comments
    WHERE user_id = $thisauthor->ID
    AND comment_post_id = ID
    AND comment_approved = 1
");
$comments_per_page = 100;
$page = isset( $_GET['cpage'] ) ? abs( (int) $_GET['cpage'] ) : 1;

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => add_query_arg( 'cpage', '%#%' ),
    'format' => '',
    'prev_text' => __('&laquo;'),
    'next_text' => __('&raquo;'),
    'total' => ceil($total / $comments_per_page),
    'current' => $page
));
```

Comment: I thought paginate_links() was used to paginate post objects - it uses the global $wp_query. Is there some way of passing it an array of comments?

Comment: Please see the reference page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links. "The function can be used to create paginated link list for any area." All the parameters are explained there. You can also post your code here so that we give you a more specific answer.

Comment: Yes - I did look at the reference, and googled for other references - still can't see how to pass a set of comments into it for pagination though.

Comment: I modified my answer.

Comment: OK - a bit of a misunderstanding on my part - I thought there would be something to handle the retrieval of comments as well. But with a bit of tinkering, and a tiny bit of code to set the LIMIT start and end from the generated page number, that works fine.

Answer (score 1):

for those looking for complete answer based on the question and @sorich87 answer.

I thought I should post solution here, for people like me (wordpress beginner).

```
//use in your custom page or custom post template 
global $wpdb;
$per_page = 5;
$page = isset( $_GET['cpage'] ) ? abs( (int) $_GET['cpage'] ) : 1;
if ($page > 1) {
    $offset = $page * $per_page - $per_page;
} else {
    $offset = $page;
}
$the_post = "select id,post_title from $wpdb->posts where post_type in ('buy','rent') and post_status='publish' "
        . "order by id desc limit $per_page offset $offset";
$details = $wpdb->get_results($the_post, OBJECT);
//do foreach to display your post details.


//paste this, where you want to display the pagination
$total = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT count(id) from $wpdb->posts where post_type in ('buy','rent') and post_status='publish' order by id desc");
echo paginate_links(array(
    'base' => add_query_arg('cpage', '%#%'),
    'format' => '',
    'prev_text' => __('&laquo;'),
    'next_text' => __('&raquo;'),
    'total' => ceil($total / $per_page),
    'current' => $page
));
```

this is how I got it working for my WordPress Website