# Authors list Pagination : result set from $wpdb->get_results()

Tags: pagination, list, sql

Using this solution :
[Paginate result set from $wpdb->get_results()](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3318/paginate-result-set-from-wpdb-get-results)

I did make my code for Authors list page template as follow:

```
<div>    
<table id="mytable"><tbody>

<?php
 // Get the authors from the database ordered by user's display name
 global $wpdb;
 $query = "SELECT ID, display_name from $wpdb->users ORDER BY display_name LIMIT 10";
 $author_ids = $wpdb->get_results($query);
$authcount = -1;

$total = $wpdb->get_var("
    SELECT COUNT(ID)
    FROM $wpdb->users
");
$authors_per_page = 10;
$page = isset( $_GET['cpage'] ) ? abs( (int) $_GET['cpage'] ) : 1;

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => add_query_arg( 'cpage', '%#%' ),
    'format' => '',
    'prev_text' => __('&laquo;'),
    'next_text' => __('&raquo;'),
    'total' => ceil($total / $authors_per_page),
    'current' => $page
));

 // Loop through each author
 foreach($author_ids as $author) :
 // Get user data
 $curauth = get_userdata($author->ID);

 // If user_ID is 1 or 24, remove them from list
 if( ! in_array($curauth->ID, array(1, 24 )) ) :
 // Get link to author page
 $user_link = get_author_posts_url($curauth->ID);
    $post_count = get_usernumposts($curauth->ID);
 ?>
<tr<?php echo $authcount % 2 ? ' class="odd"' : ''; ?>>
<td>
<?php echo $authcount; ?>
</td><th scope="row">
<a href="<?php echo $user_link; ?>" title="<?php echo $curauth->display_name; ?>"><?php echo $curauth->display_name; ?></a>
</th><td>
( <?php echo $post_count; ?> )
</td></tr>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php $authcount = $authcount + 1; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>

</tbody></table><br /></div>
```

But every page-number link display only the authors list from 1 to 10, whereas the database have a list of atleast 50-authors.
Please help me to find out the error and its rectification.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: no need for the sql part, you can get a list of author IDs with `get_users_of_blog()`

Answer (score 3):

Your Query is

```
"SELECT ID, display_name from $wpdb->users ORDER BY display_name **LIMIT 10**";
```

This Sql statement requests the first 10 authors

Comment: but when I removed this **LIMIT 10**, then it is displaying all the authors on one page. what is the solution then?

Answer (score 2):

Like edelwater already wrote, you're missing to properly specify the LIMIT clause for your needs:

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants (except when using prepared statements).
>
> With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1):

[12.2.8. SELECT Syntax (MySQL Manual)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html)

So for a 1 based `$page` number, it's (literally) `LIMIT ($page-1) * $pagesize, $pagesize` where `$pagesize` is 10 in your case.

Comment: @ hakre, but Even after setting the LIMIT as
LIMIT $page, 10
I couldn't able to get proper paginated links, All the page links displays only from Author ID's no:1 to no:9

Comment: @syed: Please `var_dump($query);` and paste it here.

Comment: @syed: also, verify you put the line `$page = isset( $_GET['cpage'] ) ? abs( (int) $_GET['cpage'] ) : 1;` before the query.

Comment: @sorich87: and `abs()` is most certainly not what you want, consider `max()`: `? max(0, (int) $_GET['cpage']` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php

Comment: hello hakre i am facing the [same problem][1] as you have solved?


  [1]: http://xrl.in/7ge8

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a solution to this by hacking together some pagination code with a modified WP_LIST_AUTHORS function.  It seems to require a Cache plugin otherwise this page can load slowly, but it does work.

The code as well as further discussions on its formatting is located over in this thread: [Modifying WP_LIST_AUTHOR Functions to output all users in a grid (and Paginate)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18639/modifying-wp-list-author-functions-to-output-all-users-in-a-grid-and-paginate)

hope that helps!

PS -- If you just want to look at a properly formatted SQL query with a LIMIT and OFFSET for pagination, you can go here:  http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/basic-pagination