# WordPress Paginate $wpdb->get_results

Tags: customization, pagination, query, wpdb

Due to a complex multisite config, I have a query which combines the posts from two blogs and I would like to **paginate the results**. I am grateful for any help. I have posted my query.

```
            $latestposts = $wpdb->get_results(

            "
            (SELECT * FROM net_5_posts
            INNER JOIN net_5_term_relationships ON net_5_posts.ID=net_5_term_relationships.object_id  
            WHERE post_type = 'post' 
            AND post_status = 'publish' 
            AND term_taxonomy_id = '151' 
            )

            UNION ALL

            (SELECT * FROM net_7_posts
            INNER JOIN net_7_term_relationships ON net_7_posts.ID=net_7_term_relationships.object_id  
            WHERE post_type = 'post' 
            AND post_status = 'publish' 
            AND term_taxonomy_id = '20' 
            )

            ORDER BY post_date
            DESC LIMIT 5",'ARRAY_A');

            foreach ($latestposts as $latestpost) {

            $da_id = $latestpost['ID'];
            $da_title = $latestpost['post_title'];
            $da_content = strip_tags($latestpost['post_content']);
            $da_content = limit_words($da_content,55);
            $da_link = $latestpost['guid'];
            $da_date = $latestpost['post_date'];
            $da_date = date('F j, Y', strtotime($da_date));

            echo '
            <div class="ldapost">
            <h2 class="lheader"><a href="'.$da_link.'">'.$da_title.'</a></h2>
            <span class="ldate">'.$da_date.'</span>
            <span class="lcontent">'.$da_content.'…</span><br>
            <a class="button btnright" href="'.$da_link.'">Continue Reading</a>
            </div>
            ';

            }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Update

I've tested this and it works on my site. A few things:

- Replace my `$query` with yours
- `global $wpdb` (per your comment regarding global variables) since it's out of scope!
- `get_results()` returns an object when not told otherwise (second parameter is the return type)
- I placed this in a plugin, but you could extract the code and place it in your theme or just put it in `functions.php`.

Here's the function:

```
function test_function() {

    global $wpdb;

    $query = "
        (SELECT * FROM wp_18_posts
        INNER JOIN wp_18_term_relationships ON wp_18_posts.ID=wp_18_term_relationships.object_id  
        WHERE post_type = 'post' 
        AND post_status = 'publish' 
        AND term_taxonomy_id = '2')

        UNION ALL

        (SELECT * FROM wp_17_posts
        INNER JOIN wp_17_term_relationships ON wp_17_posts.ID=wp_17_term_relationships.object_id  
        WHERE post_type = 'post' 
        AND post_status = 'publish' 
        AND term_taxonomy_id = '2')";

    $total_query = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (${query}) AS combined_table";
    $total = $wpdb->get_var( $total_query );
    $items_per_page = 1;
    $page = isset( $_GET['cpage'] ) ? abs( (int) $_GET['cpage'] ) : 1;
    $offset = ( $page * $items_per_page ) - $items_per_page;
    $latestposts = $wpdb->get_results( $query . " ORDER BY post_date LIMIT ${offset}, ${items_per_page}" );

    foreach ($latestposts as $latestpost) {
        $da_id = $latestpost->ID;
        $da_title = $latestpost->post_title;
        $da_content = strip_tags($latestpost->post_content);
        $da_content = wp_trim_words($da_content, 55);
        $da_link = $latestpost->guid;
        $da_date = $latestpost->post_date;
        $da_date = date('F j, Y', strtotime($da_date));

        echo '
        <div class="ldapost">
        <h2 class="lheader"><a href="'.$da_link.'">'.$da_title.'</a></h2>
        <span class="ldate">'.$da_date.'</span>
        <span class="lcontent">'.$da_content.'…</span><br>
        <a class="button btnright" href="'.$da_link.'">Continue Reading</a>
        </div>
        ';
    }

    echo paginate_links( array(
        'base' => add_query_arg( 'cpage', '%#%' ),
        'format' => '',
        'prev_text' => __('&laquo;'),
        'next_text' => __('&raquo;'),
        'total' => ceil($total / $items_per_page),
        'current' => $page
    ));
}
```

### Original Post

The paginate_links function is independent of your query. Given a few parameters, like the total number of items and the current page, it can provide the pagination that you're looking for. So you need to calculate:

1. The total number of items
2. The current page number, 1-based
3. The offset for the mysql limit statement.

I was thinking something like this (untested, sorry!):

```
$query = "
    (SELECT * FROM net_5_posts
    INNER JOIN net_5_term_relationships ON net_5_posts.ID=net_5_term_relationships.object_id  
    WHERE post_type = 'post' 
    AND post_status = 'publish' 
    AND term_taxonomy_id = '151' 
    )

    UNION ALL

    (SELECT * FROM net_7_posts
    INNER JOIN net_7_term_relationships ON net_7_posts.ID=net_7_term_relationships.object_id  
    WHERE post_type = 'post' 
    AND post_status = 'publish' 
    AND term_taxonomy_id = '20' 
    )";

$total = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (${query}) AS combined_table" );
$items_per_page = 5;
$page = isset( $_GET['cpage'] ) ? abs( (int) $_GET['cpage'] ) : 1;
$offset = ( $page * $items_per_page ) - $items_per_page;
$latestposts = $wpdb->get_results( $query . " ORDER BY post_date LIMIT ${offset}, ${items_per_page}" );

foreach ($latestposts as $latestpost) {
    // Your code here ...
}

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => add_query_arg( 'cpage', '%#%' ),
    'format' => '',
    'prev_text' => __('&laquo;'),
    'next_text' => __('&raquo;'),
    'total' => ceil($total / $items_per_page),
    'current' => $page
));
```

References:

- [This answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/3319/5927) about pagination.
- [This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9291656/210827) about counting in MySQL unions.

Comment: thanks, hmmm couldn't quite get that working with my query, I might be missing something.

Comment: I've updated my answer to be more clear, with some pseudocode. Hopefully this works! If not, please comment! :)

Comment: Hey Weberwithoneb thanks for sticking with me on this one. I have tried the updated query but it brings up a blank, no errors, just no results. I can confirm that the query in my question does work. do I need to add any globals?

Comment: Ok I've updated my answer with tested code. Please comment with questions!

Comment: Wow!! You are a GENIUS and I want to say a BIG THANK YOU!! Works like a dream!! Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to hear it!!

Answer (score 0):

```
// This worked great for me so much thanks! I just adapted for what I needed. Right in template file, Sweet!
global $wpdb;
// QUERY HERE TO COUNT TOTAL RECORDS FOR PAGINATION $total = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*)
$post_per_page = 10;
$page = isset( $_GET['cpage'] ) ? abs( (int) $_GET['cpage'] ) : 1;
$offset = ( $page * $post_per_page ) - $post_per_page;

// QUERY HERE TO GET OUR RESULTS $results = $wpdb->get_results

// PHP FOR EACH LOOP HERE TO DISPLAY OUR RESULTS
// END OUR FOR EACH LOOP

// PAGINATION HERE IN NICE BOOTSTRAP STYLES
<?php 
echo '<div class="pagination">';
echo paginate_links( array(
'base' => add_query_arg( 'cpage', '%#%' ),
'format' => '',
'prev_text' => __('&laquo;'),
'next_text' => __('&raquo;'),
'total' => ceil($total / $post_per_page),
'current' => $page,
'type' => 'list'
));
echo '</div>';
?>
```