# Conditional sorting with variable using WP Query

Tags: wp-query, wpdb

I have for example this posts in WP:

```
Name   ID  Date 
JohnA  6  01012020
JohnB  7  01022020
KateA  7  05052021
SamA   4  01022020
SamA   4  01022022
```

How I can order by date, but also put posts with ID before others for every user logged in (also ordered by date ) ? Other words -  how to sort with conditional logic, using variable for example current user ID in it, so each user will see own posts before other one's.

Comment: So you're saying that the user sees their posts first (by date) and then all other authors by date, or by both author id then date?

Comment: Every user sees his posts at the up, then all others.

Comment: This example is simplified to understand the problem

Comment: So is the order that you're showing in your question, the order that you expect the results to be in?  Is the `date` field, the `post_date` or is this a custom field?  Is the date stored as a date time field?

Comment: No, it's a simplified example of database fields. I can easily do this task with 2 qeuries but this isn't possible to do with pagination, so I need only 1 query.

Comment: In other words, I need it ordered by date, but also show rows with current user ID before all other rows ( for each user this fields are different )

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand of your problem, the solution would be to use the SQL operator "UNION", as shown in the following example.

```
SELECT res.id, res.name, res.date, res.rowOrder
FROM (
    SELECT id, name, date, 1 as rowOrder 
        FROM users u
        WHERE u.name = 'JohnD'
    UNION
        SELECT id, name, date, 2 as rowOrder 
        FROM users u
        WHERE u.name != 'JohnD'
) res
ORDER BY res.rowOrder, res.date;
```

You can see my test on : https://sqltest.net/#1547933

I let you add the Wordpress wrapper ([WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/)) to your query.

### Edit

You can easily add a pagination as in [this issue](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53194/wordpress-paginate-wpdb-get-results)

Comment: I'd guess that orderby only orders the second query, not the complete union. But you'd probably get away with that because the roworder 1s would be generated first anyway

Comment: But you'd probably need to wrap that in another query anyway so that WP_Query can add the paging to it.

Comment: Maybe I didn't fully understand the request, but I think the `UNION SQL` operator associated with the `get_results` function of the $wpdb global should be enough. @Horhe can you give us the code of your query, it will be easier for us to understand and help you.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, you are right I need WP_Query to add the pagination  to it @Rup

Comment: @HorheGarcia : You can easily add a pagination to a `$wpdb->get_results` method as in this [other issue](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53194/wordpress-paginate-wpdb-get-results).

Comment: @Rup : I agree with your comment. I think I have corrected the query now: [see the following link](https://sqltest.net/#1547933)...

Answer (score 1):

You can put the condition in your select and then use that for sorting.

```
SELECT ID, post_author = 6 as featured_author
FROM wp_posts
ORDER BY featured_author DESC, post_created DESC
```

Comment: This way I'll have only rows with post_author = 6 ?

Comment: @HorheGarcia No, this will give you all posts and you will have a column "featured_author" with a value of either "1" or "0" depending if the post belongs to author_id = 6. It's a boolean in the SELECT part of the SQL, like a calculated value. If you wanted to only have rows with post_author = 6, you would need to put it in the WHERE part of the SQL.