# How to implement pagination into a wpdb->result query?

Tags: plugin-development, pagination, wpdb

How can I integrate pagination for the results fetched from wpdb query in my custom plugin?

here is the query

```
global $wpdb;
    $data = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM `wp_gj73yj2g8h_hills_school_data` " . $where_query_text  . ";"));
```

Comment: Please see: https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination

Comment: I see it;s related to retrieving the post and WP_Query. In my case, I want to retrieve the bunch of data that has statistical data, images, and map. I am struggling hard. I have referred this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3318/paginate-result-set-from-wpdb-get-results?rq=1 but failed with that too.